# Deactivating and activating an E-mail form

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I'm trying to get the code below to keep an E-mail form deactivated until 6 seconds after the page is fully loaded. What can I do to make it work like that?

```
var inActive = true;

      function inActive() {
      if (!inActive)
      return true;

      inActive = true;
      document.getElementById("myForm").disabled = true;

      setTimeout(function() {
      inActive = true;
      document.getElementById("myForm").disabled = false;
        }, 1000);

      return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to hard code the duration. Instead you should call the activate using asynchronous call.

Anyways, here is the working code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var inActive = true;

    function inActivate() {
        if (!inActive)
            return true;

        inActive = true;
        document.getElementById("myForm").disabled = true;

        setTimeout(function () {
            inActive = true;
            document.getElementById("myForm").disabled = false;
        }, 4000);

        return true;
    }
    inActivate();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Sandeep how do I call the activate with asynchronous call?

Comment: You can set the disabled to true by default (HTML). Once the load is complete, then you can set the disabled to false. If you are using jquery - you can do $(function() { //set disabled to false }); or use jQuery blockUI plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) which will block the UI if any load is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

```
window.setTimeout(function() {  
    // Do whatever you need
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout("your function to be called to activate an email form", 6000);
```